# Surface color on Apache Echarts.js

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

let's have a mountain (as defined by the surface 3d function below in the html). I want to plot over this region, the temperature anomalies. Now, the colors are from the z values. But, would like the colors represent the temperature anomalies, not the z values. In other words, how to set surface color ?
Thanks in advance !!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ECharts 3D Surface Plot</title>
    <!-- Include ECharts library -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.2.2/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts-gl/dist/echarts-gl.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100vh;">

<div id="chart" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>

<script>
    // Initialize ECharts instance
    var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart'));

    // Set the options for the 3D surface plot
    var option = {
        grid3D: {
            boxWidth: 200,
            boxDepth: 80,
            viewControl: {
                autoRotate: true,
                beta: 10,
                alpha: 30
            }
        },
        xAxis3D: {
            type: 'value'
        },
        yAxis3D: {
            type: 'value'
        },
        zAxis3D: {
            type: 'value'
        },
        visualMap: {
            dimension:2,    // Updated to use the 3rd dimension for color mapping
            max: 2, // Set the range of values for color mapping
            min: -2,
            calculable: true,
            inRange: {
                color: ['#0000ff', '#ffffff', '#ff0000'] // Blue to White to Red gradient
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'surface',
            data: (function () {
                var data = [];
                for (var x = -Math.PI * 2; x <= Math.PI * 2; x += 0.1) {
                    for (var y = -Math.PI * 2; y <= Math.PI * 2; y += 0.1) {
                        var z = Math.cos(x) + Math.sin(y); // Replace with your terrain elevation function
                        var temperatureAnomaly = Math.sin(x) + Math.cos(y); // Replace with your temperature anomaly function
                        data.push([x, y, z, temperatureAnomaly]);
                    }
                }
                return data;
            })(),
            shading: 'color'
        }]
    };

    // Set the options to the chart
    myChart.setOption(option);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I try set surface color, but i get only the z values colors. When i try dimension:3, i get just black colors.

Comment: Here are two offical examples which might be helpful: [Example1](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=metal-surface&gl=1), [Example2](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=image-surface-sushuang&gl=1)